# "Список недавно открытых файлов" в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Не могу найти адекватную реализацию "Список недавно открытых фалов" для WPF.

Список думаю хранить в `Property.Settings.Default`. Там можно хранить список типа `StringCollection`.

Comment: Ну да, для этого settings и придуманы. А в чём вопрос?

Comment: Не могу команду прикрутить к созданным по этому списку пунктам меню

Comment: Ну, Settings в любом случае модельный объект, так что вам нужнa ещё VM.

Comment: Вы `MenuItem`ы создаете вручную в коде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Список файлов у нас храниться в настройках программы: `Property.Settings.Default.RecientlyList`

Model

```
public class RecentlyFileModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public ICommand OnClickCommand { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class RecentlyFiles_VM : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<RecentlyFileModel> _recentList = new ObservableCollection<RecentlyFileModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<RecentlyFileModel> Items
        {
            get { return _recentList; }
            set
            {
                Items = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }

        public RecentlyFiles_VM()
        {
            Items.Add(new RecentlyFileModel() { Title = "test.jpg", FileName = @"c:\test.jpg" });
        }

        public RecentlyFiles_VM(StringCollection StringCollection)
        {
            foreach (string fName in StringCollection)
            {
                Items.Add(new RecentlyFileModel() { Title = Path.GetFileName(fName), FileName = fName });
            }
        }

        private ICommand _command;
        public ICommand OnClick
        {
            get { return _command; }
            set
            {
                _command = value;
                foreach (RecentlyFileModel rfm in Items)
                {
                    rfm.OnClickCommand = _command;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

View

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        RecentlyFiles_VM _recentlyList;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //  RecentlyFiles_VM _recentlyList = (RecentlyFiles_VM)DataContext;
            _recentlyList = new RecentlyFiles_VM(Properties.Settings.Default.RecentlyFilesList);
            this.DataContext = _recentlyList;
            _recentlyList.OnClick = ParamsCommand;
        }

private RelayCommand<string> _withParamCommand;
        public ICommand ParamsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (null == _withParamCommand)
                    _withParamCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(ExecuteParameterCommand);

                return _withParamCommand;
            }

        }

        private void ExecuteParameterCommand(string obj)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            MessageBox.Show(obj);
        }
```

XAML:

```
<Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding OnClickCommand}"/>
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding FileName}"/>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Test" Command="{Binding OpenRecentFile, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <MenuItem Header="CMD With Params" Command="{Binding ParamsCommand, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="Test"/>
        </Menu>
```

Теперь мы умеем читать список и создавать динамически меню, а так же запускать команду на выполнение. Остается добавить возможность добавлять, удалять из списка, ну и что-нибудь на ваше усмотрение.

Просьба в комментариях прокомментировать данный подход и правильность реализации. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, я бы сделал `RecentlyFileModel` immutable (то есть без сеттеров), а так вроде хорошо.

Comment: @VladD когда по вашему мнению добавляется файл в список?

Comment: Как только его открыли (если открытие было успешным). При этом если файл уже был в списке, то он должен по идее взлететь вверх. И как мне кажется, нужно тут же сохранить изменения «на диск» (то есть, `Settings.Default.Save()` или там оно).